# Error Consulta con clausula Where IN & Like, SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Eh estado ejecutando la siguiente consulta pero a pesar de que no tiene ningun error (a mi apreciación) no me devuelve los registros que indico, se las comparto:

```
select * from TableHeadCount
where JobPosition in ('Assembler','Material Handler Operations','Material Handler','Shipping & Receiving Handler','Administrative Assistant',
'Security Specialist', 'Student', 'Quality Control Inspector', 'Warehouse Administrator','Tool & Model Maker','Operations Trainer',
'Inspection & Repair Operator','Entrenador de Operaciones')   
or (JobPosition like '%Tecnico%' 
or JobPosition like '%Técnico%'
or JobPosition like '%Technical%'
or JobPosition like '%Technician%'
or JobPosition like '%Coordinator%')
and Director = 'America Garza'
```

Mi objetivo es que de mi tabla "TableHeadCount" solo me muestre los registros con los puestos que especifique en la clausula Where IN o que muestre los puestos que contengan las palabras clave mencionadas con el Like pero que tengan como director a "America Garza", siguiendo esta logica solo me deberia devolver los registros donde cumpla los puestos mencionados con el director mencionado, pero al ejecutarlo me trae los registros de los puestos mencionados de varios directores y no del que especifique. Hay algo mal en mi query? Talvez se me paso algo pero no logro entender que es, bueno les agradeceria mucho su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías tener en cuenta la precedencia de operadores lógicos en T-SQL. Como el operador AND tiene prioridad sobre el OR tu cláusula WHERE es equivalente a:

```
where JobPosition in ('Assembler','Material Handler Operations','Material Handler','Shipping & Receiving Handler','Administrative Assistant',
'Security Specialist', 'Student', 'Quality Control Inspector', 'Warehouse Administrator','Tool & Model Maker','Operations Trainer',
'Inspection & Repair Operator','Entrenador de Operaciones')   
or ((JobPosition like '%Tecnico%' 
or JobPosition like '%Técnico%'
or JobPosition like '%Technical%'
or JobPosition like '%Technician%'
or JobPosition like '%Coordinator%')
and Director = 'America Garza')
```

Por lo tanto, los que cumplan la primera condición se incluirán independientemente del valor del campo Director.

Deberías utilizar paréntesis para cambiar esa precedencia de operadores:

```
where (JobPosition in ('Assembler','Material Handler Operations','Material Handler','Shipping & Receiving Handler','Administrative Assistant',
'Security Specialist', 'Student', 'Quality Control Inspector', 'Warehouse Administrator','Tool & Model Maker','Operations Trainer',
'Inspection & Repair Operator','Entrenador de Operaciones')   
or (JobPosition like '%Tecnico%' 
or JobPosition like '%Técnico%'
or JobPosition like '%Technical%'
or JobPosition like '%Technician%'
or JobPosition like '%Coordinator%'))
and Director = 'America Garza'
```

En realidad los paréntesis que separan las cláusulas OR serían prescindibles puesto que no tienen ningún efecto:

```
where (JobPosition in ('Assembler','Material Handler Operations','Material Handler','Shipping & Receiving Handler','Administrative Assistant',
'Security Specialist', 'Student', 'Quality Control Inspector', 'Warehouse Administrator','Tool & Model Maker','Operations Trainer',
'Inspection & Repair Operator','Entrenador de Operaciones')   
or JobPosition like '%Tecnico%' 
or JobPosition like '%Técnico%'
or JobPosition like '%Technical%'
or JobPosition like '%Technician%'
or JobPosition like '%Coordinator%')
and Director = 'America Garza'
```

Answer (score 4):

Sólo para completar la respuesta de Asier, dejo aquí traducido lo que dice la [documentación sobre la precedencia de operadores en Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Cuando una expresión compleja tiene varios operadores, la precedencia
> de los operadores determina la secuencia de operaciones. El orden de
> ejecución puede afectar significativamente el valor resultante.
>
> Los operadores tienen los niveles de precedencia que se muestran en la
> siguiente tabla. Un operador en niveles superiores es evaluado antes
> que un operador en un nivel inferior. En la siguiente tabla, `1` es el
> nivel más alto y `8` es el nivel más bajo.

| Nivel | Operadores |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `~` (Bitwise NOT) |
| 2 | `*` (Multiplication), `/` (Division), `%` (Modulus) |
| 3 | `+` (Positive), `-` (Negative), `+` (Addition), `+` (Concatenation), `-` (Subtraction), `&` (Bitwise AND), `^` (Bitwise Exclusive OR), `|` (Bitwise OR) |
| 4 | `=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `<>`, `!=`, `!>`, `!<` (Comparison operators) |
| 5 | `NOT` |
| 6 | `AND` |
| 7 | `ALL`, `ANY`, `BETWEEN`, `IN`, `LIKE`, `OR`, `SOME` |
| 8 | `=` (Assignment) |

> Utilice paréntesis para anular la precedencia definida de los
> operadores en una expresión. Todo lo que está entre paréntesis se
> evalúa para producir un solo valor. Ese valor puede ser utilizado por
> cualquier operador fuera de esos paréntesis.

En tu caso, para que la precedencia aplique del modo esperado, puedes meter el `IN` y los `OR` entre paréntesis.

```
CREATE TABLE TableHeadCount (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    JobPosition VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Director VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL

);
```

```
INSERT INTO TableHeadCount (JobPosition,Director) 
  VALUES 
  ('Assembler','America Garza'),
  ('Student','America Garza'),
  ('Inspection & Repair Operator','Fake'),
  ('Inspection & Repair Operator','America Garza'),
  ('Assembler','America Garzaa')
;
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
select * from TableHeadCount
where 
  (
      JobPosition in (
                      'Assembler','Material Handler Operations','Material Handler','Shipping & Receiving Handler','Administrative Assistant',
                      'Security Specialist', 'Student', 'Quality Control Inspector', 'Warehouse Administrator','Tool & Model Maker','Operations Trainer',
                      'Inspection & Repair Operator','Entrenador de Operaciones'
                     )   
      or JobPosition like '%Tecnico%' 
      or JobPosition like '%Técnico%'
      or JobPosition like '%Technical%'
      or JobPosition like '%Technician%'
      or JobPosition like '%Coordinator%'
  )
  and 
      Director = 'America Garza';
```

| id | JobPosition | Director |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Assembler | America Garza |
| 2 | Student | America Garza |
| 4 | Inspection & Repair Operator | America Garza |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8OFZ39Ar)